# Can load image, but when I load it again within the second round of a loop it crashes

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Title, it returns the error "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist" I have tried changing the root = tk.Tk
() to root = tk.TopLevel() as suggested by previous users who received the same error.

The script goes through a list of image files on a CSV file, the idea is to create a slideshow and the CSV file saves the formats of the different slides.

The "iam" if statement refers to an "image and message" slide which is what's currently drawing the errors. I have tried opening the image using the same calls as the regular image slide type but it crashes in a new and unique way every time.

I can post more information as needed but if anybody has any ideas as to how I could fix this I would love to hear them.

```
    # import required modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import display_save

# Initialize tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()


# Retreive data table
frame = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Establish variables
show_size = len(frame.index)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("teapot.png"))
bg_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("teapot.png"))
time_step = 1

# Initialize image label as empty
img_lbl = Label(root)
img_lbl.pack()

# Initialize text label
txt_lbl=Label(root)
txt_lbl.pack()

img_txt_lbl = Label(root)
img_txt_lbl.pack()


# Keypress event management
res_lbl = Label(root)
def keypress(event):
    global res_lbl
    if(event.char == "f"):
        root.attributes('-fullscreen', False)
    elif(event.char == "r"):
        res_lbl.pack()
        res_lbl.config(text= str(root.winfo_width()) + " x " + str(root.winfo_height()))


def keyrelease(event):
    global res_lbl
    if (event.char == "f"):
        root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    elif (event.char == "r"):
        res_lbl.pack_forget()

# bind key events
root.bind("<KeyPress>",keypress)
root.bind("<KeyRelease>",keyrelease)

x = 0
# Function to rotate images
def runtime():
    global x
    global img
    global img_lbl
    global txt_lbl
    global img_txt_lbl
    global bg_img


    if(x <= show_size):
        df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
        df = df.iloc[[x - 1]]

        t = df.iloc[0]['type']
        date_remv = df.iloc[0]['date_remove']

        # If type is image, initialize
        if(t == "img"):
            img_lbl.pack()
            txt_lbl.pack_forget()
            img_txt_lbl.pack_forget()

            root.config(bg='white')
            p = df.iloc[0]['data']
            temp = Image.open(p)
            temp = temp.resize((root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()))
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)

        # If type is message, initialize
        elif (t == "msg"):
            txt_lbl.pack()
            img_lbl.pack_forget()
            img_txt_lbl.pack_forget()

            m = df.iloc[0]['data']
            c = df.iloc[0]['data2']
            txt_lbl.config(bg =c, text=m, anchor=CENTER, height=20, wraplength=1000, font=("Arial", 50))
            root.config(bg=c)

        # If type is an image and a message, initialize
        elif (t == "iam"):
            img_txt_lbl.pack()
            txt_lbl.pack_forget()
            img_lbl.pack_forget()


            p = df.iloc[0]['data']
            temp = Image.open("teapot.png")
            temp = temp.resize((root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
            temp = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)

            bg_img = temp

            m = df.iloc[0]['data2']
            img_txt_lbl.config(text=m, height=root.winfo_screenheight(), width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), wraplength=1000, font=("Arial", 50), compound='center')
            root.config(bg='white')

        # Check to make sure the slides list is up-to date
        if(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_remv, display_save.format) <= datetime.datetime.now()):
            index = df.iloc[0]['id']
            display_save.delete_row(index)

        root.after(time_step * 1000, runtime)
    else:
        x = 0
        root.after(0, runtime)
    x = x + 1
    img_lbl.config(image=img)
    img_txt_lbl.config(image=bg_img)


runtime()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create a new image using `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` you have to make sure that image variable stays during the entire time your code runs. This means for example if you create the first image in a variable `img` then you must not use the SAME variable for a new image because once the old  image is rewritten it's gone. So the trick here is to store the old image somewhere where it doesn't change. To do this simply append the old image to a new list where you can store all PHOTOIMAGEs as a memory. I recently answered the same type of question here and there might be a better explanation: [How to create multiple images in tkinter that can scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136048/how-to-create-multiple-images-in-tkinter-that-can-scale/74136871#74136871).

I haven't tested if this works but I believe it should work.